# how to execute batch command (imagemagick) with java

Tags: java, imagemagick

I used the terminal command to convert all the images in the folder into RGB images using imagemagick tool

> "C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My
>   Documents\NetBeansProjects\Archiveindexer\resources\T0003SathyabamaT\Active\CBE_2014_03_02_FE_04_MN_IMAGES_CONVERTED"
>   is my image folder

terminal command:

```
 myimagefolder> mogrify -colorspace RGB *.jpg
```

This works fine. But when run this using java it is not working

```
File destpathfinalconv = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/admin/My          Documents/NetBeansProjects/Archiveindexer/T0003SathyabamaT/Active/CBE_2014_03_02_FE_04_MN_IMAGES_CONVERTED");
         ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-colorspace RGB", destpathfinalconv.toString(),
                     "*.jpg");

      pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

      Process p = pb.start();
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          System.err.println(line);
      }
      System.err.println("Error "+p.waitFor());
```

> System is throwing error "mogrify.exe: unrecognized option
>   `-colorspace RGB' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/4254. Error 1"

Any idea please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying '-colorspace RGB' as a single argument, but it should be two arguments. And you should combine the path and file and search pattern into a single argument. The constructor of ProcesBuilder should be called like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mogrify", "-colorspace", "RGB",
  destpathfinalconv.toString() + "\\" + "*.jpg");
```

Comment: mogrify.exe: unable to open image `C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\Archiveindexer\T0003SathyabamaT\Active\CBE_2014_03_02_FE_04_MN_IMAGES_CONVERTED\*.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.
Error 1. This also shows error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
       "mogrify", 
       "-colorspace",
       "RGB", 
       destpathfinalconv.toString(),
       "*.jpg");
```

Explanation: Each String argument in the ProcessBuilder ends up as a "word" (according to shell parlance) or a separate parameter in the resulting execve call.

Combining "-colorspace RGB" results in a single parameter to mogrify, which is the (unknown) option "-colorspace\ RGB".